# Lista de estados onde cada nó estará ligado a uma árvore de busca binária de cidades

Tags: c, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados

Boa tarde,

Queria saber como fazer uma lista encadeada de estados onde cada nó estado está ligado a uma árvore de busca binária de cidades a partir das informações extraídas de um arquivo.

Minha dúvida surgiu após sucessivas tentativas de gerenciar minha estrutura usando ponteiros serem frustradas por erros `[Error] dereferencing pointer to incomplete type`.

Pelo erro emitido supus que o problema estaria na declaração do tipo de ponteiro, já que meu compilador poderia não estar associando o `typedef struct celCidade apontadorCidade;` a um ponteiro para *struct* celCidade por exemplo, então tentei utilizar *cast* através do `malloc();`, porém o erro persiste.

Na função `insereCidade();` está o erro apontado.

- Onde está o erro?
- Como posso corrigi-lo?
- Tem como simplificar o código?

**Código completo para teste:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct celCidade apontadorCidade;
typedef struct celEstado apontadorEstado;

typedef struct{

    char nome[30];
    int populacao;
    int beneficiarios;
    int qtdCidades;
    float idh;
    apontadorCidade *Arv;
    apontadorEstado *proxEstado;
}celEstado;

typedef struct{

    char nomeCidade[30];
    char nomeEstado[30];
    int populacao;
    int beneficiarios;
    float idhm;
    apontadorCidade *esq;
    apontadorCidade *dir;

}celCidade;

typedef struct{

    celEstado *inicioLista;

}tipoListaEstado;



int insereCidade(celCidade newCidade, celEstado *auxEstado){

    if(auxEstado->Arv == NULL){
        auxEstado->Arv = (apontadorCidade*)malloc(sizeof(celCidade));
        auxEstado->Arv->beneficiarios = newCidade.beneficiarios;
        auxEstado->Arv->idhm = newCidade.idhm;
        auxEstado->Arv->populacao = newCidade.populacao;
        strcpy(auxEstado->Arv->nomeCidade, newCidade.nomeCidade);
        strcpy(auxEstado->Arv->nomeEstado, newCidade.nomeEstado);

        return 0;
    }

    if(auxEstado->Arv->nomeCidade[0] >= newCidade.nomeCidade[0]){
        insereCidade(newCidade, auxEstado->Arv->dir);
    }else if(auxEstado->Arv->nomeCidade[0] < newCidade.nomeCidade[0]){
        insereCidade(newCidade, auxEstado->Arv->esq);
    }

    auxEstado->qtdCidades++;
    auxEstado->beneficiarios += newCidade.beneficiarios;
    auxEstado->populacao += newCidade.populacao;
    auxEstado->idh += newCidade.idhm;
    strcpy(auxEstado->nome, newCidade.nomeEstado);

    return 0;
 }

bool buscaEstado(tipoListaEstado *listaEstado, celEstado *auxEstado, 
celCidade newCidade){

bool retorno;
auxEstado = listaEstado->inicioLista;

    do{
        retorno = false;

        if(strcmp(newCidade.nomeEstado, auxEstado->nome) == 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            auxEstado = auxEstado->proxEstado;  
            }
          }while(retorno == false || auxEstado->proxEstado != NULL);

    return false;   
}


void carregaArquivo(FILE *arquivo, tipoListaEstado *listaEstado){

    celEstado *auxEstado;
    celCidade newCidade;

    while(fscanf(arquivo, "%[^;],%[^;],%d;%f;%d", &newCidade.nomeCidade, &newCidade.nomeEstado, &newCidade.populacao, &newCidade.idhm, &newCidade.beneficiarios) != EOF){

        if(listaEstado->inicioLista == NULL){
            listaEstado->inicioLista = (celEstado*)malloc(sizeof(celEstado));
            strcpy(listaEstado->inicioLista->nome, newCidade.nomeEstado);
            auxEstado = listaEstado->inicioLista;
        }

        if(strcmp(newCidade.nomeEstado, auxEstado->nome) == 0){
            insereCidade(newCidade, auxEstado);
        }

        if(buscaEstado(listaEstado, auxEstado, newCidade) == false){
            auxEstado->proxEstado = (celEstado*)malloc(sizeof(celEstado));
            auxEstado = auxEstado->proxEstado;
            insereCidade(newCidade, auxEstado);
        }   

    }


}


int main() {

    FILE *arquivo;

    tipoListaEstado listaEstado;


    arquivo = fopen("data.csv", "r");

    if(arquivo == NULL){
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo");
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você está passando apenas o valor da sua struct, quando finaliza a função a memória é devolvida para o sistema e seus ponteiros são perdidos. Recomendo utilizar ponteiro de ponteiro, assim você passa a struct por referencia e não por valor

Comment: no caso transformar o `typedef struct celCidade apontadorCidade` em `typedef struct celCidade *apontadorCidade`? e depois declarar um `apontadorCidade *auxCidade`?

Comment: a struct está correta. Na hora que você chama a função insereCidade, passa assim: insereCidade(&newCidade, &auxEstado). E a sua função ficaria int insereCidade(celCidade **newCidade, celEstado **auxEstado). Ao invez de utilizar apenas auxEstado passa a utilizar *auxEstado. Onde **auxEstado vai ser um ponteiro que aponta diretamente para auxEstado da sua função carregaArquivo, assim não perde os dados ao termino da função.

Comment: O problema não está na perda de dados, pelo menos não que eu tenha notado, o problema é de compilação mesmo. o erro `[Error] dereferencing pointer to incomplete type` está impedindo o programa de ser compilado e testado

Comment: Ao invez de utilizar typedef struct celCidade apontadorCidade; tenta colocar direto na struct assim:
typedef struct celCidade{
    char nomeCidade[30];
    char nomeEstado[30];
    int populacao;
    int beneficiarios;
    float idhm;
    struct celCidade *esq;
    struct celCidade *dir;
}apontadorCidade;

Comment: Dá erro de tipo não conhecido por causa dos ponteiros de celCidade, já tentei isso kkkk

Answer (score 0):

Uma solucão seria:

```
typedef struct celCidade apontadorCidade;
typedef struct celEstado apontadorEstado;

struct celEstado{

    char nome[30];
    int populacao;
    int beneficiarios;
    int qtdCidades;
    float idh;
    apontadorCidade *Arv;
    apontadorEstado *proxEstado;
};

typedef struct celEstado celEstado;


struct celCidade{

    char nomeCidade[30];
    char nomeEstado[30];
    int populacao;
    int beneficiarios;
    float idhm;
    apontadorCidade *esq;
    apontadorCidade *dir;

};

typedef struct celCidade celCidade;
```

Mas não consigo entender porquê você declara os tipos `apontadorCidade` e `apontadorEstado`. Porquê não usar `celEstado` e `celCidade` diretamente??